# Where is the path of sublime in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, sublime-text

I want to set my Sublime Text path in FileZilla.

Where and how do I set the path?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to share a bit more info on your setup? How have you installed `sublime`? Can you do a `which sublime_text` from a terminal?

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Answer (score 28):

Firstly, find the path of Sublime Text by running in terminal:

```
which subl
```

The result is `/snap/bin/subl` in my case.

Then go to the *Edit* menu in FileZilla and select *Preferences*. In *Preferences* select *FileType Association* under the *File Editing* option. Then insert the Sublime Text path got from `which subl` command.

Comment: using sublime text 3

Comment: It's okay which subl command give you the path of sublime. Than use that path

Comment: `which subl` returns `subl not found`

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal thanks. the result is /usr/bin/subl in my case